# Deserializing the result of jQuery.Serialize (to an array - not to a form)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to deserialize the result of jQuery.Serialize to an array (or other similar JavaScript data structure)?

I know about the jQuery.Deserialize plugin but I don't think you can get the deserialized data; i.e., it is for deserializing back to the original form (from which you previously serialized the data).

Comment: did you try using $(jQuery.Serialize()).toArray() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want it as an array , try using serializeArray instead of serialize, that gives you the elements mapped to their names as an associative array.

[.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Answer (score 0):

As @SpiXel has shown you can use `serializeArray` to generate an array from a `<form>` element.

There is no function available in jQuery to convert the string generated by `serialize` function. You have to do something as shown below

```
var paramString = $("#cform").serialize();
var jsonString = '{"' + paramString.replace(/[&=]/g, function(a, b) {
    return (a == "&" ? ",\"" : "\":");
}) + '}';
var object = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax, Hope It will help you.

```
 var d = $('#form4').serializeArray(); 
 d.push({lead_id : $("#lead_id").val()});
```